# Input PATH like file, but no upload

Tags: html, file, firefox, path, firefox-addon

I am currently building a web based system for our local network and would like the user to select the location (network drive and sub-directory) on  web form, where certain files are stored.

Does anyone know of a simple way to input a PATH via browsing, rather than a text input.
I was initially thinking of using < input type="file" /> but without the multipart-form and then reading the input with javascript/jQuery, but this is a security issue and not available.

I can change the Firefox browsers config settings, but I haven't been able to find out how to allow this.

Is there an Firefox addon or flash utility that can accomplish this.

My only solution to date is for them to open up a file explorer and paste the path into the form.

Answer (score 0):

If Firefox is up-to-date, you can use the HTML5 Filesystem API: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/toying-with-the-html5-filesystem-api/

Current compatability: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader